# Desktop Icons - creation

Tags: icons, desktop-icons

How can I create Icons on the Desktop. Using Ubuntu 14.04(Unity). I think terminal will help, the problem is that I am new to Ubuntu. Linking can not work I Tried it. Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of icons are you trying to create on the desktop?  Simple pictures, links to files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Browse to `/usr/share/applications/`
2. Copy the `.desktop` file of the application you want to your desktop.

Comment: :) you mean copy .desktop file (not icon!) to the your desktop.